# jquery get not working after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I would like to make the redirect URL from user submit. but , it's not working.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#form1").on("submit", function(event) {
   var username=$('#username').val();
   var jqxhr = $.get( "/get_url.php",{ username: ""+username+""}, function(data) {
   alert("Go to "+data);
   $(this).attr('action', data);
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

but if i put **event.preventDefault();** It will show the URL i want to redirect.
(sorry for my poor english)

Comment: where you want to redirect and when?

Comment: Farhan : I get the URL from get function and redirect after submit by checking username

Comment: I want to change the action method and post all my data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update HTML, change submit to button.

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="form_submit" />


<script>
 $(function() {
   $("#form_submit").on("click", function() {
       var username=$('#username').val();
       var jqxhr = $.get( "/get_url.php",{ username: username}, function(data) {
                       $("#form1").attr('action', data);
                       $("#form1").submit();
                    });
     });

    $("#form1 input[type='text']").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#form_submit").trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: give me your sample url, also please check in console if there is any error

Comment: use console.log(data) in get function and check what is in console

Comment: I'm working in localhost.
and want get return value from /get_url.php 

If i put **event.preventDefault();**  inside function It's will give me the value.
But,If i remove "event.preventDefault(); " It's not working don't know why

Comment: I have made some changes, please check

Comment: actually I want to replace action form
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="user_login.php">

the "user_login.php" will get from /get_url.php and replace the default 

without using "event.preventDefault();"

Comment: but if you will not use prevetDefaut() function then it will redirect without completing get function. Although i have removed comments for updating form action

Comment: the URL change but form not submit

Comment: so you want to submit the form on that url which you are getting through get function. got it let me update this

Comment: the code you put 
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="form_submit" />
still not working

Comment: oh , sorry it's working now. i forgot to put button.

Comment: but it I want to use enter  to submit what can I do P

Comment: let me update code. you have one form on page and all are text fields ?

Comment: I have updated code to manage enter key on input type text fields. hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the URL from get_url.php and then submit the form

Then you have to :

1. Prevent form from submitting
2. Get the correct url
3. Create another form with same contents and different action
4. Submit the new form.

   ```
   <script>
   function submit_form_to_url(form, url) {

   var new_form = $("<form action='"+url+"' method='"+form.attr("method")+"'>");

   new_form.html(form.html());

   $("body").add(new_form);

   new_form.submit();
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#form1").on("submit", function(event) {

       event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting

       var username=$('#username').val();

       var jqxhr = $.get( "/get_url.php",{ username: ""+username+""},             function(data) {

           alert("Go to "+data);

           submit_form_to_url($(this), data);

       }

   });

   });

   </script>
   ```

Comment: It's normal because the form will submit unless you use event.preventDefault(). Check the edit though :)

Comment: can I re-submit again with new URL I got from "get_url.php" with post data?

Comment: just got alert and page not change

Comment: I changed the method, now it's creating another form. I think it's gonna work for you now

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the action method and post all my data to it

To send all the inputs you can use `serialize` and for the post request use ajax `$.post` request :

```
$.post( "/get_url.php", $("#form1").serialize());
```

> I would like to make the redirect URL from user submit

To redirect user you can use :

```
window.location.replace("Url HERE");
```

**Full Example :**

```
$(function() {
    $("#form1").on("submit", function(event) {
        $.post( "/get_url.php", $("#form1").serialize(), function(url) {
            window.location.replace(url);
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.